# MVC4 client Get Async vs Calling business-Logic/Repositories to fetch data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

We are migrating from Web forms to MVC4 architecture. We have our Web API and MVC in the same solution. So we few choices:

1) Either we could call Web API from our MVC controller like is done by the other clients:
   var response = await client.GetAsync("api/method");

Since both MVC and Web API are in the same project, we were confused           whether it would make sense to put this extra HTTP call which could be avoided if we directly access the repository/businessLayer exactly the same way we are doing in Web API. (Little duplication of code but performance benefit)

2) We have many resources with multiple such requests. For example we have to invoke 8-10 different repositories for fetching data.

POSSIBLE SOLUTION (What should we do for fetching data from MVC controller):
1) Should we call these multiple repositories through client.GetAsync method which would asynchronously bring all the data from repositories. Asynchronous implies parallel logic which would be faster. Con is that we have all the way extra HTTP call for invoking different APIs.
OR
2) Should we directly call these 8-10 repositories one by one as is done ultimately by these Web APIs? I don't see much benefit of this since it would be synchronous. Only benefit could be that we are avoiding extra HTTP call here. But this comes at extra cost of duplicate code. (Accessing same BL/Repository code from Web API and MVC). I don't know if its possible to use some asynchronous approach to call the Repositories from MVC controller?

Which one should we go with? An extra HTTP call with power of asynchronous programming OR directly accessing Repositories OR if someone can suggest mixture of two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure is an interesting question and I had to make this decision as well. The most interesting part is the authentication for users. MVC as well as Web API both have an good authentication process. Where an API of course is made for stateless http calls (using a token on every authenticated request) and MVC uses cookies and all the other stuff.

For me, it was a better choice to keep this authentication separate, while still pointing to the same database and thus not calling my API every time I want to access the database. Even though your API is running on the same server, I am sure that calling your database directly is faster.

I think you don't have that much duplicated code if you do it right.
To start with, have an application Core project, if it is even bigger, have a database core and a web core. Your business logic should do the *business* for your application. If it is a api or an mvc application, I assume you want to achieve the same goal with both applications: Get or update your data in a safe and controlled manner. But don't make the mistake to do this to much. Some logic is ok to have in the controllers of your mvc/api project.

From a maintenance point of view: It is much safer to have typesafe calls to your BL's then doing this over an API request, that might change in the feature (or you have to update the version everywhere).

Architecture, it's a fun world.

Comment: I didn't get the last part? 
I was planning to call Web API from MVC application with async await feature introduced in .NET 4.5 with MVC4. 
If i go with directly calling repository, i won't be able to access repositories asynchronously as per my current knowledge. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I am not sure what 'repositories' in this context you are talking about, but the way I understand you: You have to execute a piece of code which you put in a `async Task` method, this method you want to execute via the API and via the MVC application. You are deciding if you want to execute that piece of code from the MVC application directly or via the API, right? Just like you can call your API with `async await` feature, you can call any other method with that as well if it is an `async Task` method. Follow this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300224.aspx